# cloning a boost::function into a pointer and calling the wrapped function with that pointer

Tags: c++, clone, boost-function

I am trying to create a copy of a `boost::function` by using a pointer and call that function using that pointer. My questions are

1. cloning a `boost::function` that way is something correct
2. the call to `fp->target()` should call or not the function wrapped
    by the boost::function?

Thanks a lot

```
  boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&my_f,my_value);
  boost::function<void()> fp* = new boost::function<void()>( f ); // clone f

  typedef void(*fptr_type)();
  fp->target<fptr_type>();  // doesn't work! Is this correct?

  fp->operator(); // doesn't compile
                  //=>error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

Comment: Why, oh *why* are you `new`ing the copy?! Please, tell me *one* sensible reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If boost::function provides a copy constructor, you can assume that it will work and take care of all the lifetime issues of f in this case ( otherwise it wouldn't be provided, and you should file a bug report on their bugzilla ).

```
fp->operator();
```

Is just the function, what you're meaning to do is:

```
fp->operator()();
```

Or as above poster:

```
(*fp)();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this code, I think that is what you want to do :

```
void my_f(void)
{
    cout << "hello";
}

int main(void){

  boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&my_f);
  boost::function<void()>* fp = new boost::function<void()>( f ); 

  typedef void(*fptr_type)();
  fp->target<fptr_type>(); 

  (*fp)();
}
```

Compiled with GCC, and that works well, I can see the cout.